# Rails4 query help, find unique records with has_many though and a joining model

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following table structure

`manufacturers` --> `products` ---> `available_sizes_products` <-- `sizes`

and the following models

```
    class Manufacturer < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_many :products
end 

    class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_many :sizes, :through => :available_sizes_products
        has_many :available_sizes_products
    end 

    class AvailableProductSize < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :sizes
        belongs_to :products
    end 

    class Size < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_many :products, :through => :available_sizes_products
        has_many :available_sizes_products
    end
```

I need to get a unique list of manufacturers, that have products in size "XL" or "L" for example.I'm getting lost in the chaining of joins etc.

```
class Manufacturer < ActiveRecord::Base

    def self.with_sizes(sizes=[])
        @sizes = Sizes.find(sizes)

        ... 

    end
end
```

Can someone help me with that ? Trying to do the Rails 4 way rather than drop down to SQL, since I need the query to run on several DBS

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to use single form of noun in belongs_to expression.

And for the query try this one:

```
Manufacturer.includes(:products).where(products: (size: "XL"))
```

I use "includes" to avoid N+1 query. Otherwise it will send two queries: one for Manufacturers and one for products. Write back, if this one doesn't fit your need.

EDIT
BTW, if you want to use exactly joining, write joins instead of includes. 
Everything is here: 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables
and here: 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working. I have a scope on `Products.with_available_size(["Xl","L"])` that works, can I join the Manufacturer on that scope to a get a distinct array of manufacturers?

Comment: Try to name your scope. For exmpl: :prods_with_size = Products.with_available_size(["Xl","L"]). Then try Manufacturer.includes(:products).where(products: :prods_with_size).I'm not sure, but try it.

Answer (score 0):

After going through the docs for [joins](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables)
this is what worked :

```
Manufacturer.joins(products: :sizes).where(sizes: {id:ids}).distinct
```

This Rails way returns the model correctly.